# Angular $stateProvider - match no route or 'blank' route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using $stateProvider with angular like this:

```
var stateConfig = function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // Redirect if no route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");

    $stateProvider.state("home.myState", {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: "/mytemplate.html",
        controller: "MyController"
    });
};
```

... and this works fine for a .NET MVC url like this (with no angular route defined):

```
http://hostname/MvcController/id
```

The issue is that sometimes the URL will be in this form:

```
http://hostname/MvcController/id#/
```

... and I can change my state definition like this:

```
    $stateProvider.state("home.myState", {
        url: "/",
        ...
```

, which matches the new URL, but no longer matches the original URL (without the trailing '#/'). How should I define the state, or configure my routing, so that it matches a URL which can either have a 'blank' route (i.e. with a trailing '#/'), or no route defined at all (no trailing '#/')

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you need to turn on the HTML5 Mode in your app.config:

```
app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Also you must set a base url in your  tag :

```
< base href="/" >
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change to this, which sets the route to have a '/' when no route is provided (and the state then matches on a route suffixed with the '/')

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider.state("home.myState", {
    url: "/",
    ...
```